# Draw a line but I get dots and curves (java)

Tags: java, graphics

I made an application that displays values from a remote sensor.
It is a modification of an existing application.

What I don't understand, I ask to "Drawline", so I am expecting a line.
What I get is "pots" or "curves"....
I get no lines anymore (before was fine), and I didn't modify anything in the Drawline painting part ...

If you could enlight me and help me solve this problem, I would be much grateful !

```
gy = parent.parent.data.getTemperatureData(nodeId, gx);

            int sy = -1;

        if (gy >= 0) { // Ignore missing values
             double rsy = height - yscale * (gy - gy0);

                 // Ignore problem values
                if (rsy >= -1e6 && rsy <= 1e6) {
                        sy = (int)(rsy + 0.5);
                }//end if

                if (lastsy >= 0 && sy >= 0) {
                     g.drawLine(lastsx, lastsy, sx, sy);
                 }//end if
            //}//end if
    }//end if
        lastsx = sx;
        lastsy = sy;
```

[image: temperature dots]

[image: light dots]

[image: humidity curves]

Comment: Please don't add screen shots of your code - it makes it very hard to run your code. Instead copy and paste into your question and use the code formatter.

Comment: But screen shots of the lines you expect vs. the "dots and curves" will be helpful.

Comment: Also try to reduce your code to those parts that are relevant for the problem. Don't just dump your entire application.

Comment: Hi all, I added screenshots of the results. Same method to display 3 differents measurements. Only the calculation varies (made in another class). Here I have a problem with the drawline which doesnt draw a line.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I only implement drawline (I havent coded dots or curves because i didnt want them). I only have one line for displaying my results: g.drawline(lastsx, lastsy, sx, sy).

Comment: I meant a screen shot of the result when it displays proper lines, vs. a screen shot of the result when it displays dots and curves. Is any of the screen shots a "proper" display? Anyway, please do as Aaron D asked and remove the code screen shots, leaving only real text code and result screen shots.

Comment: Just at a glance: the if-nesting might be skewed. I suspect lastx/lasty assignments to happen more than the drawing from them to the next point, so gaps appear. Better rewrite the whole to do a single [**drawPolyline**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolyline%28int[],%20int[],%20int%29) as it has a better join quality (especially on print media).

Comment: @Joop : yes but I don't know the total points of my line, because it is "live"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a java issue, but rather an issue caused by my C code on sensors. I called 3 different read functions and they all send the values, that is why all the graphs are made at the same time, and this makes a display issue. Java code is fine, I need to learn C !